# Rails ActiveRecord select tickets that are open & have not been replied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So I have the following scope to find out all open tickets:

```
scope :opened, -> { where(status: 'open') }
```

Now I know that my active record `has_many` messages:

```
 has_many :messages, as: :commentable
```

But now, how can I link the scope query so it selects by open, and `messages count > 0`?

Pretty new to ruby, would like to know more about this!

Comment: `scope :open_message, -> { joins(:messages).where('messages.count > ?', 0) }` something like this ?

Comment: Are both of these code pieces on your Tickets model?

Comment: Yes they both are there

Answer (score 1):

I'd add a `counter_cache` column to commentable. That way when a new message is created it updates the count, so you can query `where("count > 0")`.

If you decide to go that route you'll have to create a migration to add the `messages_count` column and backfill the existing values, but this is the clean way to do it. More on `counter_cache` here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html (search page for 'counter_cache')

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, you'd probably implement this as an `EXISTS` correlated sub-query, so you get a semi-join from `Ticket` to `Message`.

You can achieve that in Rails with:

```
Ticket.where(Message.where("messages.ticket_id = tickets.id").exists)
```

It's not very pretty, but it's very high performance, and similarly ...

```
Ticket.where.not(Message.where("messages.ticket_id = tickets.id").exists)
```

Having said that, a counter cache would perform better for scanning large numbers of tickets, but counter caches can get out of sync with the real numbers, and a scheduled job to raise an alert if they get out of sync would be advisable. I'm not sure that I would do that if I just wanted to know whether a child record exists or not -- I'd probably use the `exists`

Edit:

For the "must be by an admin" I would favour ...

```
Ticket.where(
  Message.
  joins(:user).
  merge(User.admins).
  where("messages.commentable_id = tickets.id").
  where(commentable_type: "Ticket").
  exists
)
```

... and a scope in User to indicate that they are an admin:

```
def self.admins
  where(admin: true)
end
```

You could also encapsulate the "message is by an admin" requirement in its own scope in the Message class so the syntax becomes:

```
Ticket.where.not(
  Message.
  by_admin.
  where("messages.commentable_id = tickets.id").
  where(commentable_type: "Ticket").
  exists
)
```

Comment: Are you simply saying that this is better performance-wise than using a outer left join?

Comment: @Jony It would definitely depend on the RDBMS and version. Many query optimisers would produce the same execution plan for either, so the difference may just be semantics. I personally prefer the semantics of the `exists/not exists` semi-join over the left outer join, but that may be a moot point if you're not writing actual SQL.

Comment: Oh the other thing about the outer join is that if you're selecting where the child records *do* exist, you have to add a unique on the result set, which is not required on a semi-join driven correlated subquery.

Comment: And what if I want to make sure that the reply is by an admin user? is this right? `where(Message.where(User.where("users.id = messages.user_id AND user.admin = TRUE AND messages.commentable_id = id")).exists)`

Comment: Seems like it gets all tickets that were answered, while I am trying to make it get all un-answered

Comment: I came up with this query, just don't know how to convert it into active records: `SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tickets
WHERE tickets.status = 'open' AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM messages INNER JOIN users ON messages.user_id = users.id WHERE messages.commentable_id = tickets.id AND users.admin = true) = 0`

Comment: @Jony just needed a `#not` in there.

Answer (score 0):

```
Ticket.opened.left_outer_joins(:messages).where.not(messages: {id: nil})
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, I understood everything expect the last part of the function. `.where('messages.id': nil)` basically looks for empty ticket, so an empty ticket has no message id so its nil by default?

Comment: No. Left outer join basically selects all records from the "left-hand side table"  of the join (i.e. `tickets`), no matter whether the a matching record of the "right-hand side table" (i.e. `messages`) exists or not. If no matching record on the right-hand side, then all the columns of the right-hand side are all set to `NULL`. So we can leverage this by picking the results that the columns of the right-hand side are all `NULL`, or simply their `id` is `NULL`.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Thanks. I didn't know this syntax. It's truly more elegant.

Comment: @Jony Sorry, I should select those results whose `messages.id` are not `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not much ruby stuff, rather SQL. Make inner join with messages so you'll get tickets only with at least one message.

```
Ticket.joins(
  "INNER JOIN messages on messages.commentable_id = ticket.id
   AND messages.commentable_type = 'Ticket'"
)
```

Then group by tickets.id and apply other scopes you need like `.where(status: 'open')`